# How to make a Bubble layout in Android in which bubble is pointing downwards?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-xml

I have tried finding out the ways. I have got the xml for incoming chat bubble and outgoing chat bubble on internet. But what I am looking for is little different. 
 
**Required Layout : Below is the layout which I am trying to build.**

[image]

***I tried to build rectangle and the downward triangle separately and placing the triangle below the rectangle*** but it gives me the below layout :

**Current Layout : This is my current layout**
[image]

The problem here is that it takes the rectangle and the downward triangle as separate entities and thus
when I give elevation to both the entities, it gives elevation to both of them separately.

***Rather, what I want is that if I can make a single layout rather than joining two layout so that :***

1. The Shadow (using elevation) can be properly adjusted along with the
   border of the layout.
2. There should be no border line between the triangle and the
   rectangle, just like it is shown in the first Image.

**Update: I want to draw it  programmatically.**

Comment: use 9 patch image for that.

Comment: I want to draw it problematically.

Answer (score 0):

this became a very common question nowadays.

- some libraries are available for that.
- one of them is ShapOfView.
- > **link:- https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView [more info about library]**

You can add dependencies as below :

- requires with AndroidX

> **dependencies {
>       implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:(lastest version)'
>   }**

- to use before AndroidX

> **dependencies {
>       implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.3.2'
>   }**

I think this library will help you.

Comment: any other way to avoid open source?